# Not able to detect UI Controls on ASP.NET Application

Tags: ui-automation

I am working on a ASP.NET application. The framework which i am using for detecting UI Controls are TestStack.White and Windows Automation. Although the object is having enough properties like
Name , Controltype -> Hyperlink and Framework Id -> "Internet Explorer". But still not able to detect control with enough properties.

Do white is able to detect Controls on ASP.NET or Web Application?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on the browser you use. Only IE exposes page content as UI automation objects quite reliably. Other browsers work better with selenium/webdriver technology: http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/ (which also supports IE)

Comment: Simon , I want to know that whether TestStack.White is able to detect ASP.NET controls. I am using IE11 as browser.